# Choose a profile when installing a quickinstaller product (Plone 4)

Tags: plone, mathjax, plone-4.x

I had performance problems when loading MathJax dynamically in my Plone 4 application. Thus, I found the Plone integration at https://github.com/collective/collective.mathjax and, as I noticed it does the same, forked it, which works well; I included a current MathJax 2.3 and changed the profile to use the "local" copy.

Now I wonder whether it is possible to choose between "online"/"remote" behaviour (load everything from `rackcdn.com`) and the "default" behaviour (use the included copy) by choosing a profile when installing the product in the *Plone QuickInstaller Tool*.

I changed the `configure.zcml` like this:

```
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:browser="http://namespaces.zope.org/browser"
    xmlns:genericsetup="http://namespaces.zope.org/genericsetup"
    i18n_domain="collective.mathjax">

  <browser:resourceDirectory
      name="mathjax"
      directory="resources/MathJax" />

  <genericsetup:registerProfile
      name="default"
      title="collective.mathjax: default"
      directory="profiles/default"
      description="collective.mathjax default profile: Includes MathJax 2.3."
      provides="Products.GenericSetup.interfaces.EXTENSION" />

  <genericsetup:registerProfile
      name="online"
      title="collective.mathjax: online"
      directory="profiles/online"
      description="collective.mathjax online profile: Load MathJax dynamically from rackcdn.com."
      provides="Products.GenericSetup.interfaces.EXTENSION" />

</configure>
```

Unfortunately I can't see the "online" profile in the QuickInstaller, not even after deinstalling the product and changing the version number.

*Update:* In the console output, I found the following text:

> INFO CMFQuickInstallerTool Multiple extension profiles found for product `collective.mathjax`. Used profile: `collective.mathjax:default`

Is there some fundamental misunderstanding, or what can I do to let people choose?

Comment: Testing your [fork](https://github.com/tobiasherp/collective.mathjax), both profiles show up and are installable without errors. Can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Additional info: I was referring to the product-list in the form, when creating a new Plonesite. There, both profiles show up. For installing a product after site creation, see keul's answer.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the choice of profiles works in the special case of a completely new site object, but not when adding a product to an existing site.  This doesn't look very consistent to me ... but it certainly seems so.

Comment: Yes you understood correctly. And also yes, it's inconsistent, respectively different ways of activating a profile: on site-creation right at the form, or after site-creation via portal_setup-import. Not much of a problem though, imho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make an answer from the helpful comments of Ida and Keul:

- **There is** (unfortunately) **no such thing as a choice between alternative profiles** (which makes the name "profiles" slightly misleading here, IMO).
- To switch between profiles, I ended in having distinct branches. The process goes like this:

  - Go to the product directory and switch to the desired branch, e.g. `git checkout <branch name>`
  - Restart Plone (otherwise it wouldn't notice the change, unless there was a new version number meanwhile)
  - re-install the product;
  - when all is well, update the `buildout.cfg` to reflect the change.

Answer (score 3):

Plone Quickinstaller (both ZMI and Plone UI) will only display **one** profile as "installation" profile. The chosen ones will be the first found (alphabetically speaking).

To manually run a profile, go to the `portal_setup` tool in ZMI, then go the the "*Import*" tab and select your wanted profile (the provided order here is a mess... you will probably find a very long combo box). At the end of the page select "*Import all steps*"

Comment: Ok, I tried this.  Afterwards, I had the definitions of both profiles ... Thus, my conclusion is: The Plone Quickinstaller doesn't intend to offer a choice of alternative profiles; when I run one manually, the other one is not removed.  Thus, I need to find another way.

Comment: Sorry, I partially misunderstood you question: no they are not "alternative" profiles. A profile is a set on configuration operation that will be executed and "do stuff". It's your duty (in that case: of the 3rd part product) to provide an uninstall profile that clean garbage.

You can manually create your uninstall profile (adding it to the product's code). I written a guide about how to uninstall Plone products: http://blog.keul.it/2013/05/how-to-make-your-plone-add-on-products.html

Comment: The answer is in your comment: There is not such thing as *alternative* profiles (which makes `profile` a somewhat misleading name for the beast, IMO). If you make this an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible to have multiple "alternative" profiles show up in Quickinstaller - you just need to 'trick' GenericSetup by registering each profile for its own (sub)package.

So the trick is to put the profile definitions inside different `configure.zcml`  files that reside in different packages (directories), and making sure to include the `<five:registerPackage package="."/>` directive in each `configure.zcml` file.

While it works, I am not sure how recommendable this trick is: I found it in the [`dexterity.membrane`](https://github.com/collective/dexterity.membrane) package, used as an example here:

First, a 'default' profile is registered completely normally in the main [`configure.zcml`](https://github.com/collective/dexterity.membrane/blob/master/dexterity/membrane/configure.zcml) of the `dexterity.membrane` package. Nothing special - **but note that it includes the `content` subpackage**:

```
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:five="http://namespaces.zope.org/five"
    xmlns:i18n="http://namespaces.zope.org/i18n"
    xmlns:genericsetup="http://namespaces.zope.org/genericsetup"
    i18n_domain="dexterity.membrane">

  <!-- Include configuration for dependencies listed in setup.py -->
  <includeDependencies package="." />
  <!-- Grok the package to initialise schema interfaces and content classes -->

  <i18n:registerTranslations directory="locales" />

  <include package=".behavior" />
  <include package=".content" />

  <!-- Register an extension profile to make the product installable -->
  <genericsetup:registerProfile
      name="default"
      title="dexterity.membrane: behaviors"
      description="Configuration for the dexterity.membrane behaviors"
      directory="profiles/default"
      provides="Products.GenericSetup.interfaces.EXTENSION"
      />
  <!-- Note that the example profile is registered in the content
       directory.  It is registered in such a way that both profiles
       are visible and can be installed separately.  Any upgrade steps
       for that profile are also defined there. -->

  <genericsetup:upgradeStep
      title="Update profile"
      description="Dummy step to fix profile registration after rename."
      source="1000"
      destination="1001"
      handler="dexterity.membrane.migration.dummy_step"
      profile="dexterity.membrane:default" />

  <adapter name="Title" factory=".indexers.Title" />

  <!-- -*- extra stuff goes here -*- -->

</configure>
```

Here's the `configure.zcml` of the said [`content` subpackage](https://github.com/collective/dexterity.membrane/tree/master/dexterity/membrane/content): Nothing special either, except for **the (second) `registerPackage` directive, and the second profile**:

```
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:five="http://namespaces.zope.org/five"
    xmlns:genericsetup="http://namespaces.zope.org/genericsetup"
    i18n_domain="dexterity.membrane">

  <!-- make this show up in the quickinstaller separately -->
  <five:registerPackage package="."/>

  <genericsetup:registerProfile
      name="example"
      title="dexterity.membrane: content"
      description="Configuration for the dexterity.membrane example content type"
      directory="../profiles/example"
      provides="Products.GenericSetup.interfaces.EXTENSION"
      />

</configure>
```